# tail in a Docker container: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, docker, memory

I'm banging my head against the wall with this issue. We're running many containers in parallel, they're running simple filesystem operations or simple linux commands and some of them under certain circumstances fail with memory allocation issues, the Docker container get OOMKiled.

I believe it is not related to the specific command. `tail` is not the only command that fails, we have also encountered `cp` or `gzip`.

We have narrowed down the issue and created a script, that will fail almost certainly when the parameters are adjusted accordingly to the underlying system.

https://github.com/keboola/processor-oom-test

The script with the default settings generates a random CSV with 100M rows (~2.5GB), copies it 20 times and then runs 20 containers running `tail -n +2 ...`. On a `m5.2xlarge` AWS EC2 instance with 1TB SSD some of the containers are OOMKilled (and some end with different errors). The processes are terminated with various errors:

```
/code/tail.sh: line 2:    10 Killed                  tail -n +2 '/data/source.csv' > '/data/destination.csv'
tail: error reading '/data/source.csv': Cannot allocate memory
tail: write error
```

(the last one is not OOMKilled)

I am not aware that `tail` should consume any memory at all. If the number of concurrently working containers is low enough, it can easily survive with 64MB of memory. With larger number of containers even 256MB is not enough mempry. I have been watching `htop` and `docker stats` and havent seen any spikes in memory consumption.

Things we have already tried

- different Docker imges (alpine, centos, ubuntu)
- different file systems (ext3, xfs)
- different os distros (centos, ubuntu)
- different instance providers (Digital Ocean, AWS)
- different types of instances and block devices
- filesystem swap/swappiness
- Docker memory swap and swappiness

Some of that helped only partially. Adjusting memory limit or number of containers made it crash again every time. We had a container with 1GB memory running simple `tail` on a large file crash with OOMKilled.

Further on what I have tried several months ago - https://500.keboola.com/cp-in-docker-cannot-allocate-memory-1a5f57113dc4. And the `--memory-swap` turned out only to be only a partial help.

Any suggestions? I am no Linux expert, so I may be missing something important. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any success with the accepted answer?

Comment: @antoine-sac yes, here's a follow-up - https://500.keboola.com/cp-in-docker-cannot-allocate-memory-part-2-369490f1a88f

Comment: What were the chances you'd written a whole blog post about it? That's great, thanks for feeding back!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you have problem with "Write cache size".

When you want to write something to the disk it's not written directly, but it's stored in write cache (called dirty_pages). It's beacause all processes don't need to wait until they get privilage to write to the disk and they continue their work. But when the process did not get priviliage to write on the disk for a long time, it's writting buffer starts to grow until it reaches your memory limit defined for container. Then it gets killed by docker.

There's a daemon called `pdflush` which takes care about flushing caches and write those dirty_pages on disk. I think you are definetly looking for parameters `vm.dirty_bytes` and `vm.dirty_background_bytes`. These two parameters are well described here [Difference between vm.dirty_ratio and vm.dirty_background_ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900221/difference-between-vm-dirty-ratio-and-vm-dirty-background-ratio).

For example if you are using memory limit `--memory=128M` and your container runs exactly one process at the time, your `vm.dirty_bytes` should not exceed 128M in bytes. `vm.dirty_background_ratio` (there is option to set ratio [% of total memory] or exact number of bytes) depends on the number of containers your are running at the same time. This value is not so important for you and you can set it somewhere between 10 to 15.

To set those variable use `sysctl -w`. For your case it should be:

```
sysctl -w vm.dirty_bytes=134217728
sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=15
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rep to comment, so here's a guess at an answer! We suffered a similar problem, and it turned out for us that disk memory isn't just how much space you use in total - there are also things called inodes which have a separate, finite number, and things like node_modules (in js) or any form of large library of small files or potentially even log files can REALLY eat up your inodes.

Try typing this into the command line (assuming you're on linux or mac)

> df -ih

If the IUse of your root (Mounted on /) is 99%, then that's your problem. You could well have a bunch of stale docker volumes with hundreds of thousands of files that are taking up all your space.

Linux often suggests a small volume (20G) for root (/) and then a large volume for your /home to fit in all your personal pictures of kittens, etc. Docker, however, unless told otherwise, puts all its data in the root mount, so you can very quickly fill it up and still have what looks like loads of space left on your server! This is usually not relevant on professional servers, but it's worth bearing in mind.

Comment: Thanks @abulafia for the suggestion, our use case is a bit different. The operation happens usually on a single large file. I have monitored `IUse%` during the whole processing time and especially when the containers started crashing and the IUse% never went over 1%. The instance was freshly started, completely empty and the root partition was 1TB. I have also tried it on a non-root RAID0 2TB partition with the same results.